# Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Iam trying to create a migration using models in my `.Net core console app` and my local `MySQL` using `entity framework core` `Code first` approach everything is good but after creating the migration and trying to use `update-database` I got this error in the `NugetPackage Console`

**Models:**

Branche

```
class Branche
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Student

```
class Student
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get;        set; }
    public string Name      { get; set; }
    public string BrancheID { get; set; }

    public Branche Branche { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
class SchoolContext:DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext()
    {
        
    } 
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> dbContextOptions):base(dbContextOptions)
    {
        
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Map entities to tables
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branche>().ToTable("Branche");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");

        // Configure Primary Keys  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branche>().HasKey(b => b.ID).HasName("PK_Branche");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(s => s.ID).HasName("PK_Student");

        //Configure Relations
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOne<Branche>().WithMany().HasPrincipalKey(b => b.ID)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.BrancheID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Student_Branche");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false).Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQL"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQL")));
    }

    public DbSet<Branche> Branches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `Branches` (
    `ID` nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    `Title` nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Branches` PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70bj.png)

I use [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.0-alpha.2)

**So please any help about this issue ?**

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` is definitely wrong. Maybe see https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/865

Comment: @Charlieface is correct. It seems, that you have been creating a migration while having the SQL Server provider enabled (an probably only later configured your app to use MySQL). If you want to use MySQL instead of SQL Server, just remove the `Migrations` folder, make sure that only `UseMySql()` is being called in your code (search for `UseSqlServer` to make sure) and then add your migrations(s) again. Then double check, that the generated code is MySQL compatible. If you find any `nvarchar`, then you are still missing a `UseSqlServer()` call. Finally, update your database.